# Webscraping Entry id from the Uniprot database search result

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Dear Stack Overflow community,

I'm working on a project where I need to extract entry IDs from the UniProt website's search results. Specifically, I'm looking to retrieve IDs like 'O00622' from HTML elements structured as follows:

```
<a class="BqBnJ" href="/uniprotkb/O00622/entry">O00622</a>
```

So, I expected that those entry id can be simply extracted using following code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.uniprot.org/uniprotkb?query=wound+healing"
res = requests.get(url)
res.raise_for_status()
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")

links = soup.find_all("a", class_="BqBnJ")

uniprot_ids = [link.get_text(strip=True) for link in links]
for uniprot_id in uniprot_ids:
    print(uniprot_id)
```

But it returns nothing. When I try print(links) it returns an empty list, although print(res.text) successfully outputs the HTML text. This leads me to believe the issue might not be with the parser, but I'm not sure what it could be.

I've even sought assistance from ChatGPT-4, but following its instructions led to the same result — an empty list. (I suspect this might be due to limitations in its capability to interact with developer tools.)

Any advice on this matter would be greatly appreciated but I would prefer a solution that doesn't involve using an API, as I'm relatively new to computer science and come from a biology background so I want to understand what is wrong in my code and to not repeat same problem in future...

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The data you see on that page is loaded from external URL via JavaScript. You can simulate this in Python via `requests`, e.g.:

```py
import requests

api_url = "https://rest.uniprot.org/uniprotkb/search"

params = {
    "fields": "accession,reviewed,id,protein_name,gene_names,organism_name,length",
    "query": "(wound healing)",
}

data = requests.get(api_url, params=params).json()

for r in data["results"]:
    print(r["primaryAccession"])
```

Prints:

```
O00622
Q15746
Q04912
P08581
Q61176
Q9VKV5

...
```

---

EDIT: To simulate `Download` button (and save all results as Json) you can use next example:

```py
import requests

api_url = "https://rest.uniprot.org/uniprotkb/stream"

params = {
    "compressed": "false",
    "download": "true",
    "format": "json",
    "query": "(wound healing)",
}

data = requests.get(api_url, params=params).json()

# show all data:
# print(data)

for r in data["results"]:
    print(r["primaryAccession"])
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. The code works, and I really appreciate your help. However, it's a bit embarrassing to request advice again, but would it be okay to ask for just one more piece of advice?

I'm not proficient in working with APIs, and when I just copy and paste the code you provided, I could only obtain 25 entry IDs. However, when I searched for 'wound healing' in Uniprot, it returned 11,811 search results.

Comment: Is it possible for you to modify the code you provided to retrieve all 11,811 entry IDs and protein names? 
Alternatively, could you point out what might be wrong with the code I posted? With that information, I believe I could extract the data I need based on my code. At least I have some understanding of my own code.

Thank you again for your time and consideration.

Comment: @SHKim I've update the answer. (Actuall, using different API - that downloads all results in one go as a Json)